# USB drive is not recognized in USB 3.0 port, in USB 2.0 is OK - in BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

My problem is that BIOS does not see my USB drive inserted into USB 3.0 port. However if i insert it into USB 2.0 port then its recognized and i can boot from it (My aim is to boot Linux in persistence mode and to install upgrades faster than in USB 2.0 because this latter took a day to upgrade Linux)
My laptop is a 2010 model ASUS N73JF and i have BIOS (BIOS mode is legacy) and Windows installed.

USB mode is set to xHCI - and i can confirm that USB 3.0 is working because its faster than in USB 2.0 port. Setting to EHCI is not a solution since i want the USB 3.0 speed.
USB Legacy support is enabled (i tried to disable it to check if it helps but then i cannot load up BIOS at startup by pushing DEL, it just jumps straight into Windows without being able to enter BIOS - then i had to find solution to access BIOS again)
I have tried UEFI mode to enable/disable - does not help (By the way i dont know whats the difference. Because i thought UEFI is the newer version of BIOS. and if i want to switch between them i have to reinstall windows and repartition everything. But i can enable/disable UEFI mode and start windows normally without anything happening. So i dont know what this option does. Maybe i mix UEFI and UEFI mode which are two distinct stuff).

Could anybody tell whats the problem?
Is it possible that problem is that BIOS is in legacy mode and i should have UEFI? I dont know if it is even possible on such an old laptop.

I would appreciate your help :)
thanks

Zsolti

Comment: What is your computer model and that of the USB? Have you tried another USB3 device?

Comment: USB 3 working in the OS does not mean that the system firmware is capable of understanding how to enumerate devices behind the USB 3 host controller per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1502326/motherboard-on-booting-does-not-identify-usb-drive-connected-through-usb-3-0-ad). It is possible that in full UEFI mode it might work better, you might have to disable "CSM" or "Compatibility Support Mode" to fully disable BIOS support and that likely *will* break Windows booting.

Comment: I have just tried another USB drive. My USB drive i want to use with Linux is Kingston DataTraveler Kyson 128 GB. If i plug it in in Windows it recognizes and works as USB 3 device. If i load BIOS it can not see it. But if i insert an older "Leef Surge 8GB" drive into the USB 3 port then Windows does not recognize it but BIOS does - BIOS even offers two modes, i think normal and UEFI options to boot from this drive. strange that if i leave the USB drives in USB 3 port then when restarting computer it freezes at POST screen. If i leave USB drives in USB 2 port then restarting is OK.

Comment: I dont have "Compatibility Support Mode" in BIOS. My BIOS has not much options available, its from 2010, an ASUS N73JF. But i have Legacy Support enable/disable. If i disable it windows boots up but i cannot access BIOS by pressing Del anymore (I had to find a tricky combination to re-access it again and enable legacy support. So i cant select USB to boot from (Boot priority to USB can be set only if USB is alredy inserted and recognised.) if legacy support is disabled. And i dont know if there is any option in windows 10 to set boot from USB without BIOS.

Comment: In bios i can choose from USB EHCI mode and xHCI mode so it should support USB 3. If i choose EHCI in BIOS then in windows it runs on USB 2 speed, if i set in BIOS xHCI mode then in windows it runs at USB 3 speed. So If there is such option available in BIOS then it shoudl support it and know the drivers. i think

Comment: I managed to update windows drivers with IObit Driver Booster and now the USB 2.0 device is recognized in USB 3.0 port (but sometimes not. It might be some bug, i have read somewhere on superuser similar case when a guy reported that sometimes the USB 2.0 device is not recognized in USB 3.0 port). But this is nothing to do with BIOS unfortunately